# Why Latex keeps replacing some of the unchanged figures even though \tikzexternalize is used?

Tags: tikz-external

I use the following in preamble and it worked fine before (I think) I change the size of a figure.

```
  \usepackage{tikzscale}  
  \usepackage{tikz}  
  \usepackage{pgfplots}  
  \usetikzlibrary{external}  
  \tikzexternalize[prefix=ext-tikz/]
```

Now `pdfLatex` keeps updating the `pdf` files of a few of the unchanged figures every time I compile the document.  I tried deleting all auxiliary files (.aux,etc), compiling with `MikTeX` and `TeXLive`, but the problem persist. What is the cause of this problem and how do you suggest solving it?

Comment: Both `tikzscale` and `pgfplots` load TikZ so you don't need it again. For the externalisation check this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55760/override-tikz-externalize-up-to-date-flag

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by re-sizing those figures by adding a very small value to the width or height.
I realized the problem is because of using the `tikzscale` package. At each run, `tikzscale` may come up with a slightly different (and random) dimension if it cannot exactly reach the desired dimension. 
The problem is solved by slightly changing the figure dimension.