# TikZ externalize fails to recognize changes: 3 years later

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am new to TikZ, please, be patient.

I see numerous questions

- [TikZ externalize fails to recognize changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124316/tikz-externalize-fails-to-recognize-changes)
- [MWE for externalize + automatic recompilation after tikz figure modification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123449/mwe-for-externalize-automatic-recompilation-after-tikz-figure-modification)
- [Override TikZ externalize "up-to-date" flag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55760/override-tikz-externalize-up-to-date-flag)

with custom scripts to detect changes in TikZ code. The answer to the last question states that

> As of May 17, 2012, the external lib comes with support for both checksum checks and diff-based checks

I see that TikZ generates files with MD5 extension but it still does not detect changes. My question is: how to avoid writing custom script to detect changes in TikZ code and make TikZ to do this automatically as described in the question I have cited?

I use the latest MikTeX under Windows.

EDIT: example code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{balance}  % for  \balance command ON LAST PAGE  (only there!)

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, arrows,matrix,positioning, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzset{external/force remake=true}
\tikzexternalize

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\NewEnviron{mytikz}[3][]%
  {\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
   \BODY
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
   \end{figure}%
  }


\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\def\mycolor{blue}

% Stackboxes
% http://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/tikz/empilements-de-cubes-sous-tikz

\newcommand{\elemcube}[4][white]
{
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!30, thin] (#2+1,#3,#4) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(0, -1, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!40, thin] (#2,#3+1,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [\mycolor,fill=#1!30, thin] (#2,#3,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle;         
}

   \begin{mytikz}[x=(90:0.4cm), y=(0:0.4cm), z=(40:0.25cm), axis/.style={->,\mycolor,thick}]{Array example}{fig:ArrayExample}

 \def\latnum{3}
 \def\lonnum{3}
 \def\timenum{3}

\foreach \time in{\timenum,...,0} {   
    \foreach \lon in{0,...,\lonnum} {
        \elemcube{\latnum}{\lon}{\time}
    }
}   

\node[\mycolor,anchor=west] at (0,\lonnum+1,0.2) {\tiny $0$};
\node[\mycolor,anchor=west] at (0,\lonnum+1.8,0.2) {\tiny 1970 Jan 01};

\end{mytikz}

\end{document}
```

I produce PDF with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape test.tex`

Comment: I just tried and it works fine for me with pdflatex. Show an example where it doesn't work and tell which engine you are using.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please, have a look at the edit

Comment: This code can not be compiled. And you didn't answer my second question.

Comment: I have updated the previous code. This is an excerpt from my original document. It does not behave like the original document: I see the PDF with `tikzexternal: picture has been externalized. This text is required to avoid empty oats.` In my original document I have my pictures inside the document.

Comment: My guess is that the culprit is the `\NewEnviron` construction: the body of the tikzpicture is always `\BODY` and thus never changes even though the def of `\BODY` changes (this depends on how things are expanded). My suggestion is to try with a normal `newenvironment` (I do not see the need for `NewEnviron` here)

Comment: You are packing your tikzpicture in an environment, actually even a \NewEnviron, and additionally use the preview package which does some additional packing (and redefines tikzpicture). How should tikz wade through all this layers to find the picture?

Comment: It is safe to remove `preview` from the code, you may comment it. Externalize will not detect changes even without `preview`.

Comment: @Bordaigorl you may be right, but how exactly is it coded? replacing with `\newenvironment` produces errors.

Comment: You can define temporary macros to #2 and #3 in the "before" part `\newenvironment{mytikz}[3][]%
      {\begin{figure}[htp]
        \def\argtwo{#2}
        \def\argthree{#3}` so you can use them later. But the problem persists because of the several layers of packing as @UlrikeFischer mentioned

Comment: If you move the `tikzpicture` begin and end inside the body of `mytikz` instead of its def it works as expected (and it is not too horrible in my opinion)

Comment: @Bordaigorl No, it does not help. When I change `\def\timenum{10}` externalize still reports up-to-date figure.

Comment: You can't hide the tikzpicture in another environment. The documentation says explicitly "[the externalization] can’t expand macros during this step, so the only requirement is that every picture’s end is directly reachable from its beginning, without further macro expansion."

Comment: I don't think that the question is unclear. AFAIK Ulrike's comment already answers the question. @UlrikeFischer could you make an answer from the comment?

Comment: Although it does not make sense to externalise a float (at all), it is possible to externalise a version of `mytikz` which wraps `tikzpicture`, even if it is an `environ` type environment, using `memoize`. I won't post code because it doesn't externalise the `mytikz` in the question. I have no idea what it would even mean to externalise a float. The idea just doesn't make sense to me at all. But you can memoize the contents of one, even if it hides a `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the tikzpicture in another environment. The documentation says explicitly

> [the externalization] can’t expand macros during this step, so the
>   only requirement is that every picture’s end is directly reachable
>   from its beginning, without further macro expansion.